# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin

Does anyone know how to resolve this in com.google.android.material version 1.11.0

I had and error in searchview like this

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400fa a=-1}

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchView

here is my code code xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".menu"
android:background="#fff">

<com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar>

<com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/searchBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchBar">
</com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my styles

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

i also add attrs.xml

```
<resources>
<attr name="colorOnSurfaceVariant" format="color" />
</resources>
```